# Storing and Retrieving a BLOB from PostgreSQL using SOCI

Tags: c++, postgresql, soci

Thank you for reading my question.

We are accessing a Postgres database through SOCI. The schema requires to have tables that contain BLOB fields. Based on PostgreSQL documentation, the ideal type to store a BLOB in a Postgres table is `pg_largeobject`.

PostgreSQL method of accessing the `pg_largeobject` involves dealing with `oid`s. But I was unable to find any details on SOCI documentation regarding this. Have anyone tried this?

Comment: Interesting library. However [`soci/tests/postgresql/test-postgresql.cpp`](https://github.com/SOCI/soci/blob/master/tests/postgresql/test-postgresql.cpp), `TEST_CASE("PostgreSQL blob", "[postgresql][blob]")` is not what you searching for?

Comment: Thank you very much. They have a test which they use oid fields to store BLOBS. This is exactly I wanted to get things going. Thanks again.